# Browser continue querying resources that must be cached from CDN

Tags: html, caching, cdn

We store only index.html on our server and turned off caching for it. When we deploy application we upload all resources to CDN and replaced links in index.

Instead of XHRs file downloads browser fetches content from cache, but for files directly linked from index.html browser sends requests to CDN and got 'Not modified' response.

How to force browser use cached files referenced from not cached index.html?
Reproduced in Chrome at least.

Answer (score 0):

That is normal behavior. '304 Not modified' means that the copy in the Browser Cache is still valid (etag) and a download is not needed.

If you clear the clients browser cache then the file from the cdn will be fetched with a "200 ok"

Comment: I understand. 304 means that request is made, but I want than will be no request at all. Browser don't make any second requests to CDN at all (for example XHR to download language file), instead of result code 'From cache' appeared in dev/ console and no request is made.

Comment: it is up to your cdn which cache-headers are send to the browser. Look for Expires, Last-Modified-Since and etag-headers in cdn-requests.